# Sliding window time series data with Python Pandas data frame

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like:

```
 1495573445.162, 0, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1
 1495573445.172, 0, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1
 1495573445.182, 0, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1
 1495573445.192, 0, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1
 1495573445.202, 0, 0.021194, 0.012161, -0.994705, 1
 1495573445.212, 0, 0.019638, 0.013718, -0.994019, 1
 1495573445.222, 0, 0.019440, 0.010803, -0.994476, 1
 1495573445.232, 0, 0.018112, 0.010849, -0.993073, 1
 1495573445.242, 0, 0.020157, 0.011154, -0.994644, 1
 1495573445.252, 0, 0.020340, 0.010040, -0.995804, 1
 1495573445.262, 0, 0.017792, 0.009857, -0.996078, 1
 1495573445.272, 0, 0.020538, 0.010239, -0.994858, 1
```

This is accelerometer data where the data frame columns are labeled `"Time stamp"`, `"Time skipped"`, `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"`, and `"label"` with the index set to `"Time stamp"`.

The sampling rate is around 100Hz. How should I create a sliding window in this case?

I came up with this:

```
def sliding_window(data, window_size, step_size):
    data = pd.rolling_window(data, window_size)
    data = data[step_size - 1 :: step_size]
    print data
    return data
```

I doubt this is the correct answer, and I don't know what to set window_size and step_size given that I have a 100Hz sampling rate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in Pandas functions to do it:

```
df["Time stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time stamp"]) # Convert column type to be datetime
indexed_df = df.set_index(["Time stamp"])           # Create a datetime index
indexed_df.rolling(100)                             # Create rolling windows
indexed_df.rolling(100).mean()                      # Then apply functions to rolling windows
```

This code is not 100% correct because the datetime conversion is not correct but it should help you get started.

Comment: `data` is passed in from a function that does `df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')` followed by `df.assign(dx=df.x.diff(), dy=df.y.diff(), dz=df.z.diff())`

Comment: With that said, do I need the first two lines?

Comment: "timestamp" column needs to be cast as datetime type to then later leverage rolling method. Pandas might automagically do that for you. I would be explicit about datetime casting. It is tricky.

Comment: When I try to do `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])` after `df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')` I get `KeyError: 'timestamp'`